# WSO2 API Manager v1.8.0 - Pass activityId (transaction id) to backend

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-bam

I can see the activityId generated in the API Manager v1.8.0 and also sent across to the WSO2 BAM after I configured the BAM event sender configuration in the API Manager. However I have another requirement around the activityId. I need to retrieve the activityId (or transaction id) in the WSO2 API Manager Synapse configuration and pass that on to the backend service. What is the way to do that?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Hi WSO2 Team, Would appreciate a quick reply on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the answer to this question is very simple actually. WSO2 API Manager adds an HTTP header by the name "activityID" when it passes the request to the backend. So that can be easily used to do end-to-end monitoring. I have been able to do that in the backend service implemented in JBoss Fuse.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware about the activity ID which you mentioned in the question.
You can pass user based information to back end service by the help of JWT concept,  here the reference link

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/12/customize-json-web-token-generation-with-wso2-api-manager-1.8.0/